# Unable to Generate Cookie and UUID .json file and login with Instabot

Tags: python, automation, bots, instagram, instagram-api

I have been trying to use the instabot library in Python to automate some of my social media work. I have two accounts, a personal and a business account. I was able to successfully log in to my personal account and set up the bot, and did all my testing there. However, I need the bot for my business account and whenever I try to login there I get the following error.

[image]

I do not get this error when I login to my personal account though. I am using the following code to initiate and login in both the instances

```
from instabot import Bot
bot=Bot(filter_users=False, filter_private_users=False,filter_users_without_profile_photo=False,filter_business_accounts=False, filter_verified_accounts=False,min_followers_to_follow=1,min_following_to_follow=1,min_media_count_to_follow=1,like_delay=1,follow_delay=1,comment_delay=1)
bot.login(username="instagram_username",password="password")
```

Can anyone help me with a solution to this issue? I have checked the config folder, one potential issue I identified is that a .json file titled 'username_uuid_and_cookie.json' is available for my personal account, which has some details shared. However, I do not see a similar file for my business account. But I am not sure if that is an issue.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update. I was able to solve the issue by changing my IP address.